# How to add comments to an image that is stored in an arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist that stores images. I want to find an image by the ID and then add a username and comment to it.

```
@Override
public Image createImage(String username, String url, String description) {
    String id = String.valueOf(Images.size() +1);
    Image N = new Image (username, url, description, id);
    Images.add(N);
    return N;

}

@Override
public Comment addCommentOnImage(String username, String img_id, String comment) {
    for(Object s : Images)
        if(s.equals(img_id)) 
        ??????? what now??

}
```

How would i go about this in Java?

Comment: Add the required fields to the class `Image` (assuming it is a custom class), create getters and setters for it, update your persistence accordingly (if you have to), and then use the setters to set the desired values... Also, `s.equals(img_id)` will always return false, you'll have to compare the Image objects' ID values with the desired id...

Comment: You'd create an object that has an image reference and properties for whatever else you want. If you want fast lookup you'd use a map, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can it in this way. You can create a class contains `imgID`, `image` and `description`.

```
public class ImgData {
private String imgID;
private Image image;
private String description;
 // getter and setters

}
```

now you can do as follows. Now you have a list type of `ImgData`. Then you can simply do as follows to set description for selected id.

```
List<ImgData> list=new ArrayList<>();
   for (ImgData i:list){
        if(i.getImgID().equals("someID")){
              i.setDescription("description about the image");
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding image object into the array list, you should keep that image object in a class and then add the comment in it

Like :-

```
  public class MyClass{
    public Int ID { get; set; }

    public Image MyImage { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }
 }
```

now add this class object in array list and get then by ID using Linq

Comment: Question about `JAVA`